# How to remove space between image and text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display the text (Facebook) exactly below the image (fb icon) without any spacing. Below is the code as of now :

```
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // prevent pixel overflow when typing
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  "assets/login_background.png",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[

           Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
              width: 180.0,
              height: 250.0,
            ),
            new Text('Facebook.',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    color: Colors.white,)),
            _textFields(),
            _signInButton(),
            _socialMediaSignIns(),
            _accountButtons()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
   }
 }
```

Currently, I see like this and would like to remove the space between image and text.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to fit image - set `fit: BoxFit.fitHeight` in Image?

Comment: That did remove some of the spacing, but it has increased height of the image and still there is some spacing that I would like to remove, so that the text is exactly below the image without any space. @AndreyTurkovsky

Comment: First of all - remove `width` and `height` from `Image`, and then check your fb_icon.png - I think it can be padding inside png-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
),
Text('Facebook.',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      color: Colors.white,))
```

It has to be no padding in this case. You can check padding exactly in png file such way:

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
  color: Colors.red,
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
),
```

This will show real borders of  your image

Answer (score 6):

Actually you should use `BoxFit.cover` to see that in effect because image has got less physical height than what is being allocated to it.

Here is the solution

```
       Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
          width: 180.0,
          height: 250.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

You could try other BoxFit to see which one suits you better.

Comment: Great answer/explanation. What a bonehead mistake I was making, your explanation solved it all thanks officer @CopsOnRoad